# Android Location Update not returning

Tags: android, location

I am trying to get android location , I have this piece of code yet location is never returned. I have searched on stack overflow.

I found this bug : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707
But there is no fix till now, or i couldnt find one. 
This is the code. Any help would be much appreciated

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    final String date = fmtForPresenter.print(dt);
    if(l==null) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 100, 200,
                new android.location.LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                                Bundle extras) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        Log.e("PROVIDER", "PRO: " + provider);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        Log.e("PROVIDER", "PRO: " + provider);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

                        lat = location.getLatitude();
                        lng = location.getLongitude();
                        presenter.getFoot(userProfile.getToken(),"public",lat,lng,date);
                        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                            lm.removeUpdates(this);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    else {
        lat = l.getLatitude();
        lng = l.getLongitude();
        presenter.getFoot(userProfile.getToken(),"public",lat,lng,date);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If i restart the phone location works again but i dont take this as a solution since i cant tell all my clients to restart their phones everytime there is a problem

Answer (score -1):

Try the blow code to get the location...and also ensure that location services are enabled in the device

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 400, 1000, this);  @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 8);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
```

Comment: i tried your code... no luck it still does the same thing ... yes i am sure that location services are enables in the device